# How to separate two different data in a JSON array with vertical pipeline as separator using python

Tags: python, json

Below is my sample json string in 2 different lines

```
{""creditNoteId"":""BSA11130181-S7"",""creditNoteUrl"":""www.twitir.com""}
{""creditNoteId"":""BSA11130181-S8"",""creditNoteUrl"":""www.googol.com""}|{""creditNoteId"":""BSA11130181-S9"",""creditNoteUrl"":""www.fesbuuk.com""}
```

I am not having issue with the first line but in the second line, which is having vertical pipeline as separator, it is giving me error

I want to print them like below

BSA11130181-S7 [www.twitir.com](http://www.twitir.com) 
BSA11130181-S8 [www.googol.com](http://www.googol.com) 
BSA11130181-S9 [www.fesbuuk.com](http://www.fesbuuk.com)

Currently I am having below error

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

Using Below python code

```html
        a = credit_note
        y = json.loads(a)
        for x in y:
          print(y["creditNoteId"], y["creditNoteUrl"])
```

Comment: Your sample does not represent valid JSON. Your code makes no sense either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

d1 = '{"creditNoteId":"BSA11130181-S7","creditNoteUrl":"www.twitir.com"}'
d2 = '{"creditNoteId":"BSA11130181-S8","creditNoteUrl":"www.googol.com"}|{"creditNoteId":"BSA11130181-S9","creditNoteUrl":"www.fesbuuk.com"}'
d2 = d2.replace('|',',') # point 1
d3 = '[{' + d2[1:-1:] + '}]'  # point 2
y = json.loads(d3)
for x in y:
    print(x["creditNoteId"], x["creditNoteUrl"])
```

This code will work for you..

1. replace | with ,
2. replace first and last curly brace with [{ and ]} to make it a valid JSON object.
3. Also make sure that d1 and d2 is string as posted in code above as json.loads expect a string argument.

Comment: How did you get rid of the double-double quotes?

Comment: s = s.replace('""','"') replace will do the trick replace ""(double) with " (single)

Comment: Just that double quotes are placed inside single one

Comment: It's just that I don't see anything in your code to handle that. You've taken the OP's sample data and edited it to suit your code. That's not very helpful

Comment: Thank you so much @JayYadav
Your answer solved my issue. You understand the issue very well :) thumbs up !!
True geek .. alright!

Comment: @JayYadav is obviously psychic